# ResourceBundle Property File Format

Tags: java

I want to ask if there a defined format for the property files to load in resource bundle.

For example, I have saved property files in http page, I download the page and provide as input to resourcebundle. But if there is some error on the server for example 404-File not found. still there would be a file, which will be an error page from the server, and will be input to resourcebundle, will resourcebundle throw some format exception, or would try to load whatever it finds.

For example, the file format is:

```
<html>
```

`<body>`
    404 - File not Found.
  `</body>`
`</html>`

Comment: This might be me, but I have absolutely no idea what you're asking.

Comment: I have updated the issue, do it explain better. Basically I want to download a property file from http file. This thing is working fine, but if there is any http error, like 404 or 500, I still have a text file, which is input to resource bundle, how would resourcebundle respond to this.

Comment: Is this Android? If you want more people who can help your issue to see it, add all the relavant tags. Android, ResourceBundle, Web Parsing, whatever you're doing.

Comment: no its not Android. I am sorry, I am not able to make you understand the issue. Let me try again.

Comment: I have a resourcebundle, which loads properties from internet resource. and works fine. Property file is like this:

Comment: I have a resourcebundle, which loads properties from internet http resource. and works fine. Property file is like this:

abc=v_abc
abc2=v_abc2
...

but for any reason, like connection failure, property file do not download, and get an error file mentioning http error like this
<html>

<body> 404 - File not Found. </body></html>

I do not check the http response status & directly give the saved file to resourcebundle. what will be the response of resourcebundle in this case, will it throw an error saying wrong file format, or will try to parse the data. I will not know the error in this case.

Comment: Edit that into the post. I don't know what you're doing, but other people do. By having a clear question, people who know the answer can help you.